# Reversing one y-axis of a plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

My code:

```
figure
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2,'semilogy','semilogy');
```

Now I want to reverse the direction of the second y-axis. I tried adding:

```
set(h2,'YDir','reverse');
```

But that results in the following error:

```
The name 'YDir' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'lineseries'.
```

Comment: You can use either 'flipud' or 'fliplr' within your plot comand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ydir` is a writeable property of a axis, not of the graphics object:

```
set(ax(2),'YDir','reverse')
```